# Extract bucket and resource name from S3 URL (regex question)

Tags: php, regex, amazon-s3

I will be receiving input which will be ANY ONE of the following. I need to devise a regex which can handle any of these and extract the validS3bucketname and validS3resourcename.

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/validS3bucketname/validS3resourcename
https://s3.amazonaws.com/validS3bucketname/validS3resourcename
http://validS3bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/validS3resourcename
https://validS3bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/validS3resourcename
```

validS3bucketname and validS3resourcename are VALID S3 values, including spaces and whatever not - I have no idea what S3 allows as valid file names.

Comment: do you want only $bucket and $resource to be extracted? or is it resource and bucket can be anything, but starting with $?

Comment: sorry, it can be anything of course - the $ sign is just my notation... i'll correct that. @Abhishek Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will match both:

```
/:\/\/s3\.amazonaws.com\/([^\/]+)|:\/\/([^.]+)\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\//
```

this simple function should wrap it nicely

```
function getS3Info($url) {
    if(! preg_match('/(?:\/\/s3\.amazonaws.com\/([^\/]+)|:\/\/([^.]+)\.s3\.amazonaws\.com)\/([^\/]+)/', $url, $a)) {
        return false;
    }

    $bucket = isset($a[2]) ? $a[2] : $a[1];
    $resource = $a[3];

    return array('bucket' => $bucket, 'resource' => $resource);
}
```

Comment: I like it and works pretty well! I dont get why you have ([^\/]+) when its a folder name and ([^.]+) when its a "domain name" though - can you help me understand that? @James

Comment: how can i match the resource name properly?

Comment: Whoops - sorry I completely forgot about the resource. Have edited my answer.

Comment: you need to change the isset to empty($a[1]) and then it works perfectly. it wouldnt work for http://s3.amazonaws.com/abced/def.mp4 otherwise

Comment: Whoops - sorry, I wasn't actually running the code! Great that it's working now.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe these can be combined. Take it as inspiration:

First case:

```
^https?://s3\.amazonaws\.com\/([^/]+)/(.+)$
```

Second case:

```
^https?://([^/]+)\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+)$
```

Comment: @jensgram - i dont know which input type it'll be

Comment: @matt74tm Then try the first case first. If no match, try the second :)

Comment: This works, the ([^/]+) gave some trouble: /^https?:\/\/s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+)\/(.+)$/

Comment: @matt74tm Yes, if you used `/` as delimiter, you must escape it within the regex: `/^https?://([^\/]+)\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+)$/` (or change the delimiter). Consider using lazy matching if you stick with the alternative: `/^https?:\/\/s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+?)\/(.+?)$/`

Comment: @jensgram - how do i match just the resource name conservatively / "lazily" in preg_match?

Comment: @matt74tm Not understood :( However, I see that I applied laziness (`.+` = greedy, `.+?` =lazy) two places. Should just have been `/^https?:\/\/s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+?)\/(.+)$/`. Did you try this, though: `/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)\.s3\.amazonaws\.com\/(.+)$/`